# How to find all the parents of a element using Xpath in selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Say by using `text()` am finding an element. Now using that element i want to traverse upwards towards parent of parent (grand parents) or even above until i get the parent element am searching for. How to achieve this ? Is there any other method which is similar to `parents()` in jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `.closest()` jquery method for that:

```
 var grandParent = $(this).closest('yourgrandparentID/Class');
```

[@jQuery docs for .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

**Description**: *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

---

### Difference between .closest() and .parents():-

#### .closest():

1. Begins with the current element
2. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
3. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set, in document order

#### .parents():

1. Begins with the parent element
2. Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied
3. The returned jQuery object contains zero or more elements for each element in the original set, in reverse document order

#### using xpath:

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <foo id="id1">
       <foo id="i2">
           <baz/>
       </foo>
   </foo>
</root>
```

and if you run this code:

> //baz/ancestor::foo[1]

this will select the closest node:

```
<foo id="i2">
```

Comment: yes closest() works with jquery api , but using Xpath how can you perform the same action as of closest().